# Unable to open X11 windows on remote machine on osx

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz

Up until last week, I have been able to open X11 windows just fine on the remote machine. Suddenly I have not been able to.

I connect to the machine with

```
$ ssh user@remote -Y
```

I am running OSX Sierra 10.12.6 and XQuartz.

When I connect to the remote machine, I attempt to launch an X11 window and get the error message.

```
$ xeyes
connect localhost port 6000: Connection refused
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Following the instructions in other questions, I have reinstalled XQuartz, reset network settings and disabled my firewall and none of these have solved the problem.

Comment: You should try [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) for that matter.

Comment: Doesn't the localhost:10.0 portion mean that the issue is on my end? Other people on the same remote machine have confirmed for me that they are not having this issue.

Comment: No, because, AFAIK what you've done, you are, a the moment where the error occurs, connected _locally_ on the remote machine.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. I was overwriting my display variable locally.